# tap and click events not fired on anchor in div which has overflow-x and actually overflowed

Tags: jquery-mobile

**HTML**

```
<div data-role='header' id="header" data-fullscreen="false" data-position="fixed" data-id="cateHeader"  >

<div style="white-space: nowrap;overflow-x: auto">
    <a href="#main"  data-role ="none" class="headerMenu active">headerMenu </a>
    <a href="#main" data-role ="none" class="headerMenu">headerMenu </a>
    <a href="#main" data-role ="none" class="headerMenu">headerMenu </a>
    <a href="#main"  data-role ="none" class="headerMenu">headerMenu </a>
    <a href="#main"  data-role ="none" class="headerMenu">headerMenu </a>
    <a href="#main"  data-role ="none" class="headerMenu">headerMenu </a>

    <a href="#main"  data-role ="none" class="headerMenu">headerMenu </a>
    <a href="#main"  data-role ="none" class="headerMenu">headerMenu </a>
</div>
```

**Javascript** (does not work):

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#main", function () {
  $(document).on("tap", "#header .headerMenu", function(e) {
  alert("a");
     if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
         $('.headerMenu').removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active');
      }
   });
 });
```

Tap and click events are not getting fired on `<a>` in a `<div>` container, which has `overflow-x` if the `<div>` overflows. If I remove some of the anchors and the parent div won't overflow, then it works.

Comment: your code works fine, you just need to place in `head` and wrap html elements in page div with id `main`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/h2xnc/3/

Comment: AAAAh...I found out the reason just now ..There is an div between body and page div..Sorry for my mistake and thanks very much..We need a debug tool for jqm on mobile device like firebug I think..

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector as below and it works fine for me.

```
$('#header .headerMenu').on('click',function(){
        alert("a");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer..while I tried ur code just now,it does not work in my android device. The key point of this problem is that the parent div is overflowed cause too many <a> in it, if delete some ones ,every thing works well. Would u please show me ur html code?

Comment: AAAAh...I found out the reason just now ..There is an div between body and page div..Sorry for my mistake and thanks very much..We need a debug tool for jqm on mobile device like firebug I think..